# Common way to customize selection style of UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I need customize view of selected/unselected cells in my UITableView, like this:

[image]

What is common way to do it?

**UPDATE:** 
If I assign image (checked/unchecked) to cell.imageView.image I got such picture (which is ugly, because circle is too big):

[image]

Comment: you have a custom cell ?

Comment: You gave the answer in the question: ***need custom**ize **view***, the picture uses most likely two images for selected / not selected applied to the `imageView` outlet of the cell.

Comment: Well, on didSelectRowAtIndexPath change the image of imageView and maintain an array of selected items.